# how to debug EventGridTrigger locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions

i have a function that is a EventGridTrigger which is triggered on blob upload.

```
 [FunctionName("EventGridTest")]
    public async Task Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
        [Blob("{data.url}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "xxxxxx")] Stream input, ILogger log)
    {
```

i am trying to debug this function locally. so when the blob is uploaded i want the break point to hit my code. I have installed ngrok and i have the http and https ngrok urls but how to use these endpoints ?

i have a url like this

```
https://xxxxxx.ngrok.io/runtime/webhooks/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName=EventGridTest
```

but what to do with this? do i have to POST ? but what will be the body of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I use this guide to do that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-event-grid-trigger-local

You have to create a new subscription, for your event;  of type webb hook and then you have to put that url in the endpoint.

So with the function running locally, you can now put a new file in the blobstorage and it will fire the event that will call your function locally and you can debug.